# Django template not rendering for category

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-urls

i had created a function for category listing. which renders successfully if URL is '/admin/category/list/'  but template extended template does not show for '/admin/category/' only shows base template.
Here is function from views.py:

```
def categoryList(request):

    q_name = request.GET.get('query','')
    c_name = request.GET.get('select_category','')
    hasform = request.GET.get('type','')
    if q_name:
        data = Category.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=q_name))
    elif hasform:
        frmid =[]
        forms = FormModel.objects.all()
        for form in forms:
            frmid.append(form.category_id)
        data = Category.objects.filter(id__in=frmid,parent_id__isnull=True)
        print(data)
    else:
        data = Category.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull=True) 

    if c_name:
        c_name = int(c_name)
        data = Category.objects.filter(id=c_name)

    paginator = Paginator(data, 10)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        data = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        data = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        data = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    all_category = Category.objects.filter(parent_id=None).order_by("name")
    return render(request,'admin/category/categorylist.html',{'categories':data,
    'q_name' : q_name,'all_category':all_category,'c_name':c_name})
```

Here is urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from category import views
app_name = "category"

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/',views.categoryList,name="categorylist"),
]
```

Comment: You don't have a URL path defined for `/admin/category/`, there is only a pattern for `/admin/category/list/`. If you want a view for the former, there needs to be a `path` call with `"/"` in your `urlpatterns` pointing at an appropriate view.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the template rather than view, can you please add template

Comment: @wmorrell url path defined in project urls.py

Comment: @DhruvAgarwal https://filebin.net/9nhwfirwton7msmk/categorylist.html?t=f2tbdr5w

Comment: @AjayKhrolia No. You have a path defined for `/admin/category/list/`. You do *not* have a path defined for `/admin/category/`. If you try to access a URL that is not defined, you won't get any results.

Comment: @wmorrell i had changed the path but it shows only admin base template only.

Comment: The Django Admin site by default renders under `/admin`, so either turn that off, or don't inject your own views into another app's URL scheme.

Comment: @wmorrell you means i cannot create that URL in /admin/category ?

Comment: If you have the Admin Site enabled, it defaults to having a `urlpatterns` entry at `/admin`. So yeah, that means if you have the Admin Site enabled, you cannot make URLs at `/admin/category`, because the Admin Site will have already defined a path using that URL.

Answer (score 0):

First, define the template path in the settings.py file like :

```
TEMPLATES = [

...

        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

...

]
```

And be sure that you created `templates/admin/category/<template name>` in your app directory.

Comment: this already done. it's not working for url 'admin/category'  else working fine.